# I'm build jhipster project through Gradle, first time project run fine but second time throws exception?

Tags: mariadb, jhipster, gradlew

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.NumberKeyedRepository]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is com.github.vanroy.springdata.jest.exception.JestElasticsearchException: Cannot execute jest action , response code : 400 , error : {"root_cause":[{"type":"index_already_exists_exception","reason":"index [user/37YxejngRkiJQ4GXn082kQ] already exists","index_uuid":"37YxejngRkiJQ4GXn082kQ","index":"user"}],"type":"index_already_exists_exception","reason":"index [user/37YxejngRkiJQ4GXn082kQ] already exists","index_uuid":"37YxejngRkiJQ4GXn082kQ","index":"user"} , message : null

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userService' defined in file [/home/manusingh/Documents/MultichannelApps/build/classes/java/main/com/webbee/service/UserService.class]:

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userService' defined in file [/home/manusingh/Documents/MultichannelApps/build/classes/java/main/com/webbee/service/UserService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userSearchRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:

Comment: @Manusingh,  this proplem occur second time when I was running my project.

Comment: ^ Please add your errors **into the question itself**, rather than adding them as comments. Use the edit link to put the question into editing mode.

Comment: Trying to create something that already exists?

Comment: @RickJames, please I am having the same issue here. Saying that **Trying to create something that already exists does not help much**

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  You will possibly find a `PRIMARY` or `UNIQUE` key that is participating in the problem.